# How to disable a subset of Pylint checks for modules matching a string or regex?

Tags: python, pylint

**I know how to disable a check entirely:**

```ini
disable = ["missing-module-doctring", ...]
```

**But I'm trying to do the equivalent of this:**

```ini
disable = [ {name="missing-module-docstring", glob="**/*/models.py"}, ...]
```

**One example:** We have many SQL Alchemy `models.py` files in our repo. It's obvious from our directory structure what the purpose of each `models.py` is. I'd really like to disable `missing-module-docstring` for any module `x.y.z.models`. A doc string will be superfluous noise. A per-file disable comment is about the same.

I have a few more scenarios like this for other checks and other module / python file naming conventions.

I looked through the config docs and didn't find anything. Is there a plugin that supports this?

If I have to go to the "two-pass solution", I guess I could run pylint once excluding `models.py` files. Then run it again filtering out everything *but* `models.py`?

For context: I run pylint at the command line, in CI, and in VS Code. I configure it in the `project.toml` but I'm open to changing this.

Comment: You haven't shown us how you're running pylint in the first place.  Are you running it by hand?  Is it part of some automated procedure?

Comment: I think those concerns are orthogonal to the problem. But I'm running pylint in several scenarios: in VS Code, at the CLI, in CI.

I'm just looking for a configuration option to disable-[check]-per-[module-name-pattern]

Answer (score 3):

https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#ignore

You can ignore directories and files by specifying the base name in regex format using the `ignore-patterns` option for pylint (see also `ignore`, `ignore-paths` or `ignored-modules`).

You can also disable pylint for a specific line, function or module using a control message as specified at https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/message_control.html#message-control